# GitHub Pipeline Integration - Always returns unable to access

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, aws-codepipeline

I've authorised our GitHub account with CodePipeline and have selected my repository, however when running the pipeline I get the following:

> **Invalid action configuration**
>
> Either the GitHub repository "*****" does not exist, or the GitHub
>   access token provided has insufficient permissions to access the
>   repository. Verify that the repository exists and edit the pipeline to
>   reconnect the action to GitHub.

I've tried with both organisation and non-organisation repositories, as well as un-authenticating AWS Pipeline and re-authenticating.

I've also followed the steps here around generating a personal access token, this too returns the same error. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-gs2

Not sure if anyone has any ideas as to what I may have missed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research and working with Amazon we have actually identified a bug in the integration!

Any one who has access to over 2000 repositories may experience issues, AWS are aware of this and we've spoken to a technical manager who is working on resolving the issue.

We simply created a new GitHub account and added access to just the few repos we needed to get around the issue.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

No need of GitHub access token for integrating GitHub with AWS CodePipeline. For me, I authorized my GitHub account with AWS CodePipeline. I didn't add any services, integrations or webhooks in my repo. CodePipeline shows me list of repositories and related branches. It works!

I hope it may work for you. If you want see my repo 
https://github.com/KumareshBabuNS/SampleAppLinux

Thanks